# Lower bound on smallest eigenvalue of sum of outer products

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V = \sum_{s = 1}^t v_sv_s^T$ be an invertible PSD matrix given by the sum of outer products, where each $v_s \in \mathbb R^d$ (these vectors are not necessarily orthogonal or linearly independent). Is there a known lower bound on smallest eigenvalue of $V$ in terms of the norms of the $v_s$?

Comment: No, the norms of $v_s$ do not give enough information for such a lower bound. Note for instance that the smallest eigenvalue will be zero if and only if the vectors $v_s$ fail to span $\Bbb R^d$, which is impossible to determine based on the norms alone.

Comment: Edited the problem to assume that this is the case. We still may have $t > d$, however.